# compass is giving Invalid CSS after "expression" was "expression" error

Tags: css, sass

I have written some style statement in some scss files. and while compiling them into css using compass, it is giving error as following

> error sass-test/sass/nr-metronic.scss (Line 4 of sass-test/sass/metronic/global/_colors.scss: Invalid CSS after " white": expected ")", was ":    (base:#ffffff...")

Here is the content of my _colors.scss file:

```css
//Component colors

$component-colors: (
 white: (base:#ffffff, font: #666),
 default: (base:#e1e5ec, font: #666),
 dark: (base:#2f353b, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue: (base:#3598dc, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-madison: (base:#578ebe, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-chambray: (base:#2C3E50, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-ebonyclay: (base:#22313F, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-hoki: (base:#67809F, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-steel: (base:#4B77BE, font: #FFFFFF),
 blue-soft: (base:#4c87b9, font: #FFFFFF)
);
```

And I am importing "_colors.scss" in a separate file like this

```
@import "colors";
```

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I just checked your example... is compiling correctly. Which version of sass/compass are you using ?

Comment: Thanks @avcajaraville for your concern. I am using Compass 0.12.7 (Alnilam). What is yours compass version? should I have to update?

Comment: Just quote property names there (i.e. "white", "default" etc) and it will work. Metronic dashboard code is a bit outdated I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some test on my local environment.

With version 0.12.7 this isnt working.

Please update to latest version **Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)**; this will work.

Another topic would be if you really need compass. Compass compiles sass through ruby, way much slower than modern sass compiler (like libe-sass, written in C and way much more faster).

For using compass helpers, there is a ton of new stuffs out there.

I will recommend you to have a look to gulp and its plugins.

Comment: I have upgrade my compass to 1.0.3 and this problem is gone. But there is a new issue. Now it is getting error while compiling the following classes.  [.datepaginator .fa-angle-right:before {
 content: "\f105"#{'/*rtl:"\f104"*/'};
}

.datepaginator .fa-angle-left:before {
 content: "\f104"#{'/*rtl:"\f105"*/'};
} ]  Can you help me out in this case

Comment: Im sorry, I don't know what is the error, or what are you trying to archive. If you need extra help, please open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: the error text is as follows:
error sass-test/sass/nr-metronic.scss (Line 21 of sass-test/sass/metronic/global/plugins/_bootstrap-datepaginator.scss: Invalid CSS after "...rtl:"\f104"*/'}": expected string, was ";")